# Get Hours for multiple venues on foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

Is it possible to get the hours for multiple venues with a single query using the foursquare API? 
Or does each venue needs to queried separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each venue must be queried individually. You can use the [multi](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) endpoint to make multiple queries in one HTTP request.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that using the multi endpoint will still count each individual query against my hourly quota? Also, is there anyway to do more than 5 requests at a time?

Comment: That is correct, each request counts against your quota, and it is not possible to make more than 5 requests in a single /multi call.